# Is RSA Privatekey generation from password reasonnable

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I want to create a sort of mini, very private messenger. To do so, I thought that it would work by having the user generate an RSA key from a string (appearing as a "password") in the front end, only sending the public key, then responding to a nonce. From my point of view, this would enable the server to never have access to the messages in any way. Since the cypher would be done client side.

Is it a good idea ?

Here is a proof of concept in python:

```py
import hashlib
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# The string to hash
s = "mysecretstring"

# Compute the SHA-256 hash of the string 3 times
hash = hashlib.sha256(s.encode()).hexdigest()


# Convert the hash to a large integer
p = int(hash, 16)

hash = hashlib.sha256(hash.encode()).hexdigest()
q = int(hash, 16)

# Generate the key using the specified values for p and q
key = RSA.construct((p * q, 65537, (p-1) * (q-1)))

# Extract the private and public keys
privateKey = key.exportKey('PEM')
publicKey = key.publickey().exportKey('PEM')

print(privateKey)
print(publicKey)
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. Since the server is generating the private key it will have access to *every* private key and thus all messages. Why not have the users generate their own keys?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk the user will be generating those client-side sorry for the confusion

Comment: Well, then what's the point of the password?

Comment: To ensure that a user can retrieve their RSA key if they lose their device or need to switch devices,by generating the key in a deterministic manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are generating the private key is deeply flawed. You are using two values which are likely not primes. Furthermore, you only will have two values of 256 bit at most, meaning that the modulus will be 512 bit. Even if these were primes (and they could be if you used a 256 bit value as *starting point*) then you'd still end up with RSA-512, which is too easily cracked.

Deriving an RSA key pair from a password is .. problematic although not impossible. The general idea is that you seed a CSPRNG and then get values from it until you can derive the two primes (of any size). The problem is that if *anything* changes w.r.t the CSPRNG then the RSA key pair would change. This can be circumvented by using a stream cipher, but the RSA key pair generator then needs to accept that stream cipher as random number generator. Even then, you'd be in trouble if anything about the RSA key pair generation changes. This is not unlikely; there are many ways for speeding up the process, and even a single change will result in an entirely different key pair.

If you are going to do this you'd use an Elliptic Curve key pair. If you need encryption you can look up (EC)IES on the internet, the Integrated Encryption Scheme. For Elliptic Curves the private key is generally just a number between 1..N or something very similar, but if you leave the topmost bit to zero then you'd still have an impossible to crack key.

The best way is to simply encrypt a private key using password based encryption (and a good PBKDF), but of course that would require a storage medium.